# How to access javascript files on Rails app when i did not add them to the precompile list?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I used a editor lib, that will load language related js files dynamically when you selected a language. In the development environment, that's fine, because assets is accessible, so the lib can access any files under assets. But in production environment, i did not add those files to precompile list, so those files are missing, and i also don't want to add them to precompile list.

So my question is  whether there is a way to access javascript files even i did not add them to precompile listi on production app?

Any suggestion is welcome,thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add them to the `public` folder, preferably in a `js` subfolder.

Comment: thanks for your reply. yes, this is a simply way. But I want to create a Gem for this lib to make it easier last time. Do you think it's a good way for gem to add them to public every time?